# Could not locate named parameter even though parameter exists without surrounding quotes

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

when i run below query in my springboot project

```
select * from activity.activity where data->'userinfo' @> '[{"name": :username}]'::jsonb
```

i get this error "Could not locate named parameter [username], expecting one of []".

The table has a data column with value as `{"userinfo": [{"name": "john"},{"lastname":"cena"}]}`

What could be the issue?

PS: i am executing the query using the entity manager to create a native query, and then calling query.getResultList().

CODE:

```
StringBuffer q = new StringBuffer("select * from activity.activity where data->'userinfo' @> '[{\"name\":").append(" :username").append("}]'::jsonb");
Query query = null;
query = em.createNativeQuery(q.toString(), Activity.class);
query.setParameter("username", getActivityDataRequest.getUserName());
return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: How do you execute this query?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i am executing the query using the entity manager to create a native query, and then calling query.getResultList(). I just now updated the question also with this info

Comment: could you please add the full code related to the query? it's not clear how the username is passed during binding.

Comment: without surrounding quotes? I can see them here: `'[{"name": :username}]'`.

Comment: @SalmanA the named parameter is not within quotes meaning its not like this `'[{"name": ":username"}]'`. Notice the quotes around :username. I saw other stackoverflow questions where people had that and obviously that wont work for sure.

Comment: Ugh? It is still inside single quotes. I believe the database library will not substitute stuff inside single quoted strings.

Comment: @SalmanA I have added the code as well for better clarity

Comment: Is there some particular reason your structure is `{"userinfo":array of objects}` instead of `{"userinfo": {"name": "john", "lastname": "cena"}}` ? It seems unnecessary unless you can have more than one value with the same key in that array.

Answer (score 0):

That is a string literal. It cannot contain a parameter. You do have a `:jsonb` parameter, though. You should use ANSI SQL casting to avoid that.

Instead you should change your query to

```
String sql = "select * from activity.activity where data->'userinfo' @> CAST(:uname as jsonb)"
// next line is psudocode
String value = JsonBuilder.newArray( JsonBuilder.newObject("name", username) ).toString();
// real code
return em.createNativeQuery(sql, ResultClass.class)
     .setParameter("uname", value)
     .getResultList();
```